# Письменная передача возгласов

Tags: междометие

Когда мы с чем-то соглашаемся, то не всегда говорим четкое "да". Часто киваем головой и утвердительно мычим. На письме этот звук, который, на самом деле, ближе всего к букве М, обозначается как "угу".
А вот что делать с отрицательным мычанием? Не соглашаясь, мы порой качаем головой из стороны в сторону и мычим нечто похожее на "неа". Но с закрытым ртом.
Так вот, как это вообще возможно передать на письме аналогичным "угу" способом? Есть ли какое-то устоявшееся обозначение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что такого междометия-звукоподражания всё-таки нет. "Не-а" и кое-что ещё, но точной передачи нечленораздельных звуков с помощью букв ещё никто не придумал. А вопрос интересный.